# Applying a two-arguments function to a matrix of arguments in R

Tags: r

I want to apply a function taking two argument and giving a scalar as out put to a matrix of N*2 containing N couples of arguments.

For example:

f(x,y) = x+y

i want to use sapply or vapply or something u suggest to for example have a matrix of :

```
x = seq(1,10,1)
y = seq(1,10,1)
z = cbind(x,y)
```

and applying z at one to f to have

f(z) = seq(2,20,2)

Comment: What's wrong with doing `x + y`, or `z[,1] + z[,2]` or `rowSums(z)`? Why use `apply` at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want to calculate the sum over the rows of a matrix, use the function `rowSums`. This is a highly optimized function just for this purpose.

If you want to apply a general function over the rows of a matrix, consider using the `apply`-function with argument `MARGIN=1`:

```
yourFunction <- function(row) return(sum(row))
apply(z,1,yourFunction)

rowPaster <- function(row) return(paste0(row,collapse=""))
apply(z,1,rowPaster)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. No the sum was an example. btw i kept looking and the function MAP did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Without an actual example it would be difficult to give an accurate answer but you maybe looking for `mapply` :

```
mapply(f, data$col1, data$col2)
```

where `data` is the dataframe, `col1` and `col2` are the two columns and `f` is the function that you want to apply to each value of `col1` and `col2`.